# how to let jackson deserialize guava multimap using the '@class' field inside json to deside the target class?

Tags: java, json, jackson, guava, multimap

I have a json like this:

```
{
  '@class':'A',
  'aProperty':{
    '@class': 'com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap',
    'a':[1,2,3],
    'b':[22]
  }
}
```

and the class A like this:

```
class A{
  Object aProperty;
}
```

when I deserialize the json, jackson cannot use the correct `keySerializer` because the type of `aProperty` is `Object`.
so I wish there is a way to config jackson and let it use the information from `@class` to decide which `keySerializer` to use, but I didn't find it.
does someone know how to config?

Comment: suggestion: don't do that, such design is terrible, it allows everyone to instantiate arbitrary objects via sending malicious json to you system, basically that is RCE

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov thx, yes, but what if it's absolutely internal use... and if don't do that, then what could I do?